# CSS grid doesn't show padding on right side with "grid-template-columns: auto"

Tags: html, css

I'm new to CSS and want to build a grid. However in this example here, my grid is expanding beyond its padding. Why's that? I added in a screenshot that shows there's no blue padding on the right side of the grid.

Shouldn't the `grid-template-columns: auto auto` cause the first two columns to decrease in size such that the last right two columns fit into the padding?
[image]

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto 5px 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>  
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">6</div>  
  <div class="grid-item">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item">8</div>
  <div class="grid-item">9</div>  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The **padding** property on your *.grid-item* class seems to be the culprit. Padding is weird when it comes to things like **width**. If you set an absolute width (say 5px) and add 20px of padding, the width of that element will be 25px. Yes, the '*auto*' should size the first two columns to fit, however the way the CSS is parsed seems to add the padding **after** the widths have been set, thus pushing it outside of the containing div element.

Comment: @EssXTee I'm a bit confused about your last sentence. Do you mean that padding is set before the width of the table? Otherwise if the padding is set afterwards, it should be at least the width of the table

Comment: The table or container (*grid-container*) has its width set first. Then inside of that, the column layout has its width set next based on your **grid-template-columns** property. The first two columns automatically set their width, while the last two have fixed widths. The total width is set to fit inside of the container (accounting for the parent's padding). *Then* after that, the padding of each *grid-item* element is processed, but because it has already filled with width of *grid-container*, it grows outside of the table/parent element.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it works but you gave the `font-size:30px` and you try to stucking your grid with `5px` and `10px`. I suggest you should use `min-content`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .grid-container {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: auto auto min-content min-content;
        background-color: #2196f3;
        padding: 10px;
      }
      .grid-item {
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
        border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
        padding: 20px;
        font-size: 30px;
        line-height: 1.5;
        text-align: center;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="grid-item">1</div>
      <div class="grid-item">2</div>
      <div class="grid-item">3</div>
      <div class="grid-item">4</div>
      <div class="grid-item">5</div>
      <div class="grid-item">6</div>
      <div class="grid-item">7</div>
      <div class="grid-item">8</div>
      <div class="grid-item">9</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see what writed @essXTee, so the problem is in padding, like he said to you...

so now I changed padding **from `padding: 20px;` to `padding: 20px 0;`**

- the first value of padding now is 20px,
- the second is 0...

1. the first need to do padding in top and bottom
2. the second is set to 0, so NO padding in left and right of `.grid-item` (that solved your bug)

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto 5px 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-item">1</div>
    <div class="grid-item">2</div>
    <div class="grid-item">3</div>
    <div class="grid-item">4</div>
    <div class="grid-item">5</div>
    <div class="grid-item">6</div>
    <div class="grid-item">7</div>
    <div class="grid-item">8</div>
    <div class="grid-item">9</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```